# How to determine Y2_MAX?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting 2 data sets via gnuplot. Values of the first one are from ~2 million to ~3 million. Values of the second are from 1000 to 2000.

After plotting from file and checking `show variables all` GPVAL_Y2_MIN is set to the correct value, but GPVAL_Y2_MAX is wrong. Its weird that GPVAL_Y_MAX is also wrong, however if plotting only the first set I get a relatively good value.

I'd like to set different ranges for *yrange* and *y2range*, but I cannot tell the possible values in advance. Of course I would like to fill the output screen as much as possible.

How could I do that?

EDIT: added currently used code

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset
# Get max and min value
plot 'test.dat' every ::1 using 3, '' every ::1 using 4
y1_max = GPVAL_Y_MAX;
y1_min = GPVAL_Y_MIN;
y2_max = GPVAL_Y2_MAX;
y2_min = GPVAL_Y2_MIN;
set terminal png size 1024, 768 #output format png
set format y "%.1s %c"
# show png in a window without save
set output '| display png:-'
set yrange [y1_min:y1_max]
set y2range [y2_min:y2_max]
plot 'test.dat' every ::1 using 3 lt rgb '#FF00FF' title "vsize" with line, \
     '' every ::1 using 4 lt rgb '#FF0000' title "rss" with line axes x1y2
```

As you see, I'm plotting the data first to get min and max values and after that creating a terminal.

Comment: Which version of gnuplot are you using, and which terminal?

Comment: gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3, and i'm using png

Comment: Can you post a minimal example data set/script?

Comment: Yes, of course I can! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a datafile to work with, my guess is that you're problem lies in the fact that in your first pass (where you collect the min/max values), you're plotting both data sets on the x1y1 axis.  On your second pass, you plot column 4 on the x1y2 axis, but you never actually reset the y2 range from anything other than the default (which you hard-coded as opposed to autoscaling).  In other words:

```
plot 'test.dat' every ::1 using 3, '' every ::1 using 4 axes x1y2
```

This brings up another question though -- Why aren't you just autoscaling?

```
set yrange [*:*]
set y2range [*:*]
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was that both data was plotted on the x1y1 axis (line 4). Thank you for spotting that mistake! :) I'm not using autoscale, because I would like to set up a margin.